# Is it possible to have a variable within a hyperlink in MSWord?

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

I want to have

http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_date_v24.xml

in Microsoft Word, but want the date to be a variable.  When clicked I want it to be filled in with yesterday's date in the format of YYYYMMDD.

An example would be

http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_20160707_v24

but want the date to change depending on the current date

Comment: The link doesn't work, for me anyway.

Comment: @Chris: e.g. http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_20160707_v24.xml

Comment: Oh, I see. You want a hyperlink with this address in your document: http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_<DATE>_v24.xml, and when <DATE> is clicked, it should fill in a date for you. This was not apparent based on the question.

Comment: @Chris Yah that's ultimately what I want.... Sorry if it wasn't so clear....